# BottomNavigationItem comportamiento raro

Tags: flutter

Estoy intentando hacer un BottomNavigationBar y cuanto tengo 3 BottomNavigationBarItem se ve perfecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se da cuando pongo un cuarto ítem

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pierde todo tipo de diseño que tenia con 3 ítems
Sinceramente no entiendo este comportamiento raro, sin embargo la navegación con los 4 items anda.

```
Widget _createBottomNavigation() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        elevation: 0,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        fixedColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.redNormal,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.how_to_vote),
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("main.menu"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_turned_in),
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("main.order"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("main.tickets"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
            label:AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("main.historial"),
          ),
        ]);
  }

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarGeneral(),
      body: _callScreen(currentIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: _createBottomNavigation(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Me contesto yo mismo, hay que poner type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, no lo había encontrado en la documentación.
Gracias!